# What is the best way to make a directory writable (application deployed on EC2)?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

With a PHP application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk, EC2, I've been using git and eb to manage my environment instances and all files. I need to change the permissions on a file directory to make it writable but git doesn't take care of transferring directory permissions. What's the simplest/fastest way to get this done from a mac?

Filezilla takes a long time to configure. I can SSH into my EC2 instance but still not sure how to change the permissions for my directory.

Answer (score 3):

Login via SSH and type next.

**Change permissions:**

```
sudo su - # log-in as superuser*
chmod 755 /path/to/your/directory
# If you just want to allow Apache to write in directory then set 666 permissions
```

**If you're an owner of directory, you don't need to log-in as superuser.*

**Change the owner if you need:**

```
sudo su -
chown user:group /path/to/directory
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [jamieb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201225/jamieb) for the correction in comments. Really I've unswered to particular [gtech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1756812/gtech)'s question:

> how to change the permissions for my directory

But of course in my opinion it's better to give permissions to e.g. `apache` (or `www-data`) user to that directory which you want to write in, to avoid such problems.

Comment: No, this is incorrect; you don't want to be SSHing into instances deployed by Elastic Beanstalk.  Your changes will get destroyed on the next application deployment or autoscale event.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this from within your application itself.  In your case, it would probably make the most sense to throw a try/catch block around the write operation and if an exception is thrown, adjust the permissions using PHP's `chmod()` function.

FYI, there's a pretty good chance that you don't want to be doing this though.  Persistent data needs to be stored either in your database or S3 (in the case of files).  Storing data locally in each instance's filesystem is a good way to lose that data the next time you do a code deployment, an autoscale event happens, or your rebuilt the environment.  It can also cause problems because you're never sure which instance serves each request due to the Elastic Load Balancer.